# Не получается разобрать JSON в MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Имею в Controllers метод который обращается к стороннему  API , хочу оттуда взять json

```
        public ActionResult JsonOrdersData(string id) 
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string URI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Kiev&appid=d418fa94e9487d29a342856a759b463e";
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URI).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

        //return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return Json(responseBody, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

и отобразить полученные данные во View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ParseResponse(data) {
    var target = $("#tabledata");
    target.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4/*data.length*/; i++) {
        target.append("<tr><td>" + data.Id + "</td><td>"
            + data.Status + "</td><td>"
            + data.coord + "</td><td>"
            + data.name + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
```

но не получается ,т.к data в js 
в таком виде 
"{\"coord\":{\"lon\":30.52,\"lat\":50.43},\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01d\"}],\"base\":\"stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":300.15,\"pressure\":1002,\"humidity\":39,\"temp_min\":300.15,\"temp_max\":300.15},\"visibility\":10000,\"wind\":{\"speed\":8,\"deg\":280,\"gust\":14},\"clouds\":{\"all\":0},\"dt\":1528188060,\"sys\":{\"type\":1,\"id\":7358,\"message\":0.0023,\"country\":\"UA\",\"sunrise\":1528163343,\"sunset\":1528221863},\"id\":703448,\"name\":\"Kiev\",\"cod\":200}"
и вывести я могу только data в виде строки . 
Как мне получить именно JSON , чтобы я мог обращаться к его свойствам : coord, lon , Lat и т.д?

Comment: Сервис погоды возвращает готовый json. Вызов метода `Json(..)` повторно сериализует его; поэтому уберите его. Просто возвращайте как строку.

Answer (score 0):

Может вам как раз не JSON нужен (который в виде строковых данных), а [JS-объект](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

По сути, котроллер у вас возвращает `string`. Метод `Json()` сериализует .NET-объект (который сейчас имеет тип `string`) в JSON. Выходит, есть два варианта:

1. спарсить ответ в контроллере и опять сериализовать его в `JsonResult`
2. передавать данные как обычную строку, которую спарсить уже на клиенте `JSON.parse(data)`.